# Ascertain exact tense from reported speech

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, progressive-aspect, reported-speech

Alphonse tells me:

> “Scott said he *had been studying* Greek for five years.”

I am trying to imagine what Scott could actually have told Alphonse. I can come up with two situations:

> a) Scott: “I *studied* Greek for 5 years.”
>
> b) Scott: “I *have been studying* Greek for 5 years.”

Comment: It's (b). For (a), the reported speech should be "... he had *studied* Greek for five years". There are some ambiguities going from reported speech to the exact quote, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

a) means that Scott no longer studies Greek.
b) means that Scott is still studying Greek.

If Alphonse told Scott that he had been studying, then b) is what he told Scott.

Comment: Vice versa. Alphonse had a talk with Scott, and Scott had told him about his (Scott's) studies of Greek.

Comment: If that's so, then Scott told him BEFORE they had the talk.

Comment: OK, I screwed it up again. But there are some tricky usages of Plueperfect that I'm going to ask about soon. Stay tuned.

Comment: If he hadn't had a talk with Scott before he had that talk, then he hadn't told him about it at the time they had their talk. (Although confusing, this is quite correct grammatically.)

Comment: No 'would' in this unreal conditional? I was taught to say-- "... _then he would not have told him_ ..."

Comment: Confusing, I agree.  Would not have is quite correct as well.  Let's simplify: "If it did not rain all last week, then it would not have rained on Wednesday."  "If it did not rain all last week, then it did not rain on Wednesday."  Both are correct, for the same reasons that both of the more complicated sentences are correct.

Comment: Those sentences may both be correct, but they're not saying the same thing. The first -- "If it hadn't rained last week, it wouldn't have rained on Wednesday" is talking about an UNREAL situation in which it didn't rain last week (or on Wednesday), hence the "would" you're more familiar with. The second is drawing conclusions from facts. "If it didn't rain last week, then [that means] it didn't rain on Wednesday."

Comment: This is also true.